# po in LLDB with swift

Tags: swift, lldb

How can I plot out variable's value in a Swift App with LLDB?

Earlier it was like `po variable_name`

Now I usually get some nasty error, like:

```
(lldb) po a
error: <EXPR>:11:5: error: use of unresolved identifier '$__lldb_injected_self'
    $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_2(     
    ^
```

Comment: Yep, debugging in Swift is currently reliant on `println`.

Comment: I had a similar debugger error that only took place when trying to inspect `let` constants; see my question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189424/how-to-view-value-of-swift-let-constant-in-xcode-6-debugger)—it turned out to be a bug in Xcode 6.

Comment: There seems to be a call for code samples / projects that exhibit these problems, from person(s) of the compiler team: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1106278#1106278 .  Any contribution to that cause would surely be appreciated by all (and would most certainly be a jolly-good-fellow)

Comment: I have made some tests with current Xcode and Swift testing printing with object. Maybe that will be helpful somehow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That error sounds like it might be because DWARF is not telling LLDB where to find your `self` object. Given the nature of Swift, LLDB needs to know the type of self in order to be able to inject an expression inside your local scope.
One way to find out if that is your problem is to do at the LLDB prompt:

```
(lldb) frame variable -L self
```

You are probably going to not see a location for it. Worth filling a bug report for, just to track your specific *repro* case.

Anyway, to get to the bulk of your question. In Swift, there is no language-sanctioned mechanism for "print description" like for ObjC, so while you can type `po self`, unless self is an Objective-C type, you will pretty much see the same thing that "p self" or even "frame variable self" would tell you - which is entirely based on the LLDB data formatters mechanism. If you want to hook into that to customize the way your Swift objects look, the obligatory reference is: http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html

Comment: It is freaking annoying that final Xcode 6 is released and they couldn't implement basic feature to watch any variable's value during debugging.

Comment: @enrico: What is the current state of the art for getting Swift symbols - is po expected to work at all on pure swift objects?  Is there a different means of getting data, and are there special build settings that are needed for this?  Thanks!

Comment: "frame variable" doesn't get same result as print description of object. It prints almost useless trash.

Comment: @poGUIst that's unfortunate - can you please give me more details about this? what data types are involved? what does 'po' give you that frame variable does not?

Comment: frame variable displays memory addresses of member references, while 'po' executes 'description' method of NSObject descendant which usually much more informative. Actually i'll try to directly call 'description' method. May be it helps. 8)

Answer (score 4):

I have made a few tests to figure out how it works with Swift, results surprised me a bit. With ObjC objects `po` calls `debugDescription` which by default calls `description`. That is clear. Unfortunately the same doesn't apply while working with Swift classes. I focused on objects rather than on printing single variables.

To make it working (`po` command in `lldb`) I had to override description. Below code I used for testing:

```
class Test : NSObject
{
    var name : String?
    var surname : String?

    override var debugDescription : String{
        return "debugDescription method"
    }

    override var description : String {
        return "description Method"
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
let test = Test()
test.name = "name"
test.surname = "surname"

(lldb) po test
description Method

(lldb) p test
(DebugTest.Test) $R1 = 0x00007fce11404860 {
  ObjectiveC.NSObject = {
    isa = DebugTest.Test
  }
  name = "name"
  surname = "surname"
}

(lldb) po dump(test)
▿ DebugTest.Test #0
  - super: debugDescription method
  ▿ name: name
    - Some: name
  ▿ surname: surname
    - Some: surname
description Method

(lldb) po print(test)
description Method
```

The thing that surprised me is that `po` on Swift objects calls `description` rather than `debugDescription` that differs from ObjC.

**EDIT**

To make it acting like with ObjC, Your class have to implement CustomDebugStringConvertible and then `po` will call `debugDescription`, which by default calls `description`. The only thing which have to be changed in my example would be adding:

```
class Test : NSObject, CustomDebugStringConvertible
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CustomDebugStringConvertible_Protocol/index.html)

Checked with `XCode 7.0.1` and `iOS SDK 9`, `Swift 2.0`

Answer (score 2):

Great answers in this page about swift defaulting to return the `description` when running `lldb) po`

If it helps, when hitting errors with lldb and Swift objects I alway tried to be in a good place.

First, tell lldb you are in a Swift context (not Objective-C):

`(lldb) settings set target.language swift`

Then I would always double-check I had imported the Framework..

```
lldb) exp import WebKit
(lldb) expr let $ds = unsafeBitCast(0x6000006d74b0, to: WKWebsiteDataStore.self)
(lldb) po $ds
<WKWebsiteDataStore: 0x6000006d74b0>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the same error, for Xcode beta4, and 
 frame variable -L self

displays something, but seems worst:

: (SwiftCollectionViewSample.DetailViewController) self =

I will definitively filed a bug, Enrico

17819707  debugger prints error: use of unresolved identifier '$__lldb_injected_self'