# How to print out the value of an an Dictionary in xcode 6.1.1

Tags: xcode, swift

When debugging in Swift, I'm having problems reading out variables. In this example, I'm trying to print out the value of the `info` object coming back from an image picker. (please see link to screenshot on dropbox)

Using `println` as you can see from the screenshot line 19 works fine. It prints out the first block of stuff on the output.

After that, I tried doing a `po info` as well as highlighting the variable and clicking the eye to print the description. Both of those printed out an empty `{}` which doesn't make sense to me, since there is clearly stuff there.

So my question is, is there an lldb command or easy way to view/print out the values of the variables - opposed to an empty `{}` I find I can't consistently observe the values of my variables which is frustrating.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45836281/debug.png

Comment: The LLDB debugger is pretty bad on Swift in general and local variables and parameters in particular. There's not much you can do; what you are already doing (println) is often the best solution. - You might try downloading Xcode 6.2 beta as I have a sense it's a bit better.

Comment: I downloaded the 6.2 beta and still the same problem. Anyways, thanks for letting me know about the state of lldb on XCode.

Comment: I can't reproduce the _exact_ problem but LLDB portrays a dictionary very badly (i.e. unhelpfully) on my machine too.

Comment: I've resorted to doing stuff like this in lldb p println(json)

Comment: maybe [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33254508/3151066) will be helpful here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Workaround for lldb limitations (example):

```
(lldb) p println(countryHash!)
```

Output example:

`[botswana: bw, united states minor outlying islands: um, isle of man: im, czech republic: cz, mauritius: mu, jersey: je, maldives: mv, uruguay: uy, barbados: bb, serbia: rs, qatar: qa, montenegro: me, grenada: gd, syrian arab republic: sy, samoa: ws, greenland: gl, iraq: iq, malawi: mw, croatia: hr, saint lucia: lc, seychelles: sc, egypt: eg, ...
]`

(*note: the list of countries is actually complete in the lldb output, but merely truncated above to avoid wasting space in this answer*)

Answer (score 1):

in Swift 2 it is:

```
(lldb) p print(dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

If you don't like the default lldb reprensentation, you can also:

```
(lldb) p dictionary.description
```